# What is a web script? How it is different from RESTFul web services?

Tags: alfresco, restful-architecture, alfresco-share

I came across this terminology while working with Alfresco. Is web script a type of RESTFul web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web scripts provide a unique way to interact with the Alfresco repository. With help of web script one can search or access contents within alfresco repository. It's basically a RESTful web service. Alfresco provides REST architecture based framework for web script. It is a simple service bound to a URI and based on HTTP.

[For more details](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/ws-architecture.html)